# Eliminating semantic-mode keyboard conflict with org-mode

Tags: emacs, conflict, org-mode, keymapping

`semantic-mode` uses <kbd>C-c</kbd><kbd>,</kbd> as a prefix for several commands. `org-mode` uses <kbd>C-c</kbd><kbd>,</kbd> for `org-priority`. I don't use `semantic-mode` within `org-mode`. Is there a way to disable `semantic-mode` just in `org-mode` buffers in Emacs 24.3?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe something like this - in init before org-mode is loaded:

```
(add-hook 'org-mode-hook (lambda () (and (featurep 'semantic) (unload-feature 'semantic))))
```

All other modes would need an inverse hook loading semantic. Not that elegant... :(

Comment: Unless there are better ideas I am probably better off just remapping the keys.

Comment: @MichaelHoffman As local keys should take precedence anyway, seems a bug in org-mode. Reporting it at emacs-orgmode@gnu.org might help.

Answer (score 0):

don't know whether you solve this or not, but your problem is exactly my problem just now, and `ede-minor-mode` shortkeys prefix`(C-c .)` conflict with the `org-time-stamp` in the same way. Anyway, I figured it out, add this to your `.emacs` or init file in the Semantic part:

```lisp
(add-to-list 'semantic-inhibit-functions
         (lambda () (member major-mode '(org-mode))))
```

the `C-c,` for org will work in org-mode, `C-c ,` for semantic will work for non-org-mode.

The above line worked for me days ago, but now, no matter where I put it, it won't work anyway, I've change it to the next configuration, and it works:

```
(add-hook 'org-mode-hook '(lambda() (set
                                 (make-local-variable 'semantic-mode) nil)))
```